# Two plots per axis using addaxis

Tags: matlab, variables, plot, axis

I have three variables I want to plot in one figure (temperature, salinity, chlorophyll). The data is split into two variables "plume" and "P7_3m".  They are both 8X5 matrices with column vectors,

```
[date salinity temperature attenuation chlorophyll].
```

I had success with ADDAXIS from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9016-addaxis .

The problem is I want to plot two lines (one solid, another dashed) of the same color for each of the three variables to compare among plume vs P7_3m. The x-axis is "xt" and labeled with "months".  Below is the code I have and does not work because after the use of ADDAXIS, the axes handle goes back to the original first plot axis.  Is there a way to access the axis plotted by ADDAXIS?  So I can plot my dashed line on the same axis as the solid line created by ADDAXIS?

I'd appreciate your help and time.  Thank you in advance!

Aya

```
figure; % start making the figure
ss=20;  % setting up the plot
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontSize', ss)
set(0,'DefaultLineLineWidth',3)

months={'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug'}; % x axis
xt=[1:length(months)];
set(gca,'xtick',xt)
set(gca,'xticklabel',months, 'fontsize', ss)
plot(xt,plume(:,2),'b')  % plot first plot, salinity
hold on
plot(xt,P7_3m(:,2),'--b')
haxes1 = gca;
set(haxes1,'XColor','k','YColor','b')
addaxis(xt,plume(:,3),'r')
plot(xt,P7_3m(:,3),'--r')
addaxis(xt,plume(:,5),[0 12],'color',[0 0.5 0])
plot(xt,P7_3m(:,5),'color',[0 0.5 0])
xlabel('months')
ylabel('Practical Salinity') 
addaxislabel(2,'Potential Temperature (^{\circ}C)')
addaxislabel(3, 'Chlorophyll a Fluorescence (ug/l)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to make use of `addaxisplot`. This should do it:

```
figure; % start making the figure
ss=20;  % setting up the plot
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontSize', ss)
set(0,'DefaultLineLineWidth',3)
hold on

months={'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug'}; % x axis
xt=[1:length(months)];
set(gca,'xtick',xt)
set(gca,'xticklabel',months, 'fontsize', ss)

% Plot on first axis.
plot(xt,plume(:,2),'b')  % plot first plot, salinity
plot(xt,P7_3m(:,2),'--b')
set(gca,'XColor','k','YColor','b')

% Plot on second axis.
addaxis(xt,plume(:,3),'r')
addaxisplot(xt,P7_3m(:,3),2,'--r')

% Plot on third axis.
addaxis(xt,plume(:,5),[0 12],'color',[0 0.5 0])
addaxisplot(xt,P7_3m(:,5),3,'--','color',[0 0.5 0])

% Add labels.
xlabel('months')
addaxislabel(1, 'Practical Salinity') 
addaxislabel(2, 'Potential Temperature (^{\circ}C)')
addaxislabel(3, 'Chlorophyll a Fluorescence (ug/l)')
```

As an aside, it really helps if you make a standalone example. In this case it would have been great if you included some dummy data for `plume` and `P7_3m`. It's not a big issue in this case as you described them and I just used rand to generate something, but maybe something that will help in future.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  The addaxisplot was exactly what I was hoping to find!  Thank you for the tip too, in the future, I will provide dummy data to make it easier to understand my problem.